# running same UI5 app locally and in WebIDE, with real and mockdata

Tags: sapui5

What I am trying to achieve: common codebase that can run unmodified on both [local installation](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/) and in the WebIDE, both with real backend and mockdata. Mostly because I really prefer VSC as editor. The app itself is a plain list of materials and descriptions, single view, nothing fancy.

Where I am at:

- local: setup works fine, both mockdata and real backend, using cors-anywhere as proxy.
- WebIDE: works only when started as "SAP Fiori Launchpad" pointing directly to Component.js to access the real backend; no luck running it with "Web Application" using index.html or test/mockServer.html (they don't boot, sap-ui-core is not found) and no mockdata (see below).

Digging around, I found that:

- as far as WebIDE is concerned, I didn't have to explicitly clone index.html to test/mockServer.html and I could just configure it to provide mockdata with a [config option](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/10/08/the-subtle-way-to-test-sapui5-app-with-odata-mock-data-with-sap-web-ide/) although this doesn't work in my case:
  [image]
- my mockserver rootUri is not relative, because I had to [match the proxy url in manifest.json](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/5bb388fc289d44dca886c8fa25da466e)

  ```
    "dataSources": {
      "ProductRemote": {
        "uri": "http://localhost:8081/http://10.0.98.194:8017/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZDEMO_FIORI_ABO_SRV/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
          "odataVersion": "2.0"
        }
      }
    }
  ```

to that in uimodule/webapp/localService/mockserver.js:

```
rootUri: "http://localhost:8081/http://10.0.98.194:8017/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZDEMO_FIORI_ABO_SRV/"
```

Here are the other relevant snippets:

index.html

[image: index.html]

test/mockServer.html

[image: test/mockServer.html]

neo-app.json

[image: neo-app.json]

Where I need help: leaving aside why the "web application" start option does not work, I'd like to understand how I could tweak the code in such a way that the cors proxy is correctly invoked on a local installation yet the implicit mockdata option in WebIDE works.

Comment: afaik, "Run with mockdata" injects a script into your index.html and does not use the mockserver.js. Did you change anything in that file?

Comment: You're correct: WebIDE does not rely on a customised test/mockServer.html but injects the script. It's basically like this one, with minor changes: https://github.com/AndreaBorgia-Abo/tutorial_openui5/blob/master/com.myorg.helloworld/uimodule/webapp/index.html

Comment: Additionally, WebIDE can only start my app directly via Components.js so index.html is out of the picture.